# Checking each character of a string (Batch Script)

Tags: batch-file

I would need a batch script that checks every character of a string and do certains actions depending on the character of the string like this:

```
set String=abc123
set Length=6
set Counter=0
:Loop
if %Counter% equ Length goto :End
set /a Counter+=1
(if character Counter of String == a) (do something)
(if character Counter of String == b) (do something else)
(if character Counter of String == c) (do another thing)
etc...
```

I am very new here and also to Batch Script, I hope my question was clear enough!

Comment: Take a look at the output when you open a Command Prompt window, type `set /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key. You should find a section of variable expansion, which shows how you can do that. For example: `Echo(%String:~0,1%`,  `Echo(%String:~1,1%`,  `Echo(%String:~2,1%`,  `Echo(%String:~3,1%`,  `Echo(%String:~4,1%`,  `Echo(%String:~5,1%`,  `Echo(%String:~-6,1%`,  `Echo(%String:~-5,1%`,  `Echo(%String:~-4,1%`,  `Echo(%String:~-3,1%`,  `Echo(%String:~-2,1%`,  `Echo(%String:~-1,1%`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a neat trick with `CMD.exe` that you can use to parse a string one character at a time. Capturing that output with a `FOR` command will allow you to do the string comparison with the `IF` command.  For the sake of brevity I just echo the letter found.

```
@echo off
set "string=abc123"

for /F "delims=" %%G in ('cmd /D /U /C  echo %string%^| find /V ""') do (
    IF "%%G"=="a" echo The character is: a
    IF "%%G"=="b" echo The character is: b
)
```

Comment: You beat me! **`;)`**

Comment: @Aacini, yeah I totally stole that code from you.